# Spring BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDaoBean'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[enter image description here][1]

Account.java

```
package com.hibernateWithSpring;
public class Account {
private int accountNumber;
private String owner;
private double balance;

public Account(){
}

public Account(int accountNumber, String owner, double balance) {
this.accountNumber=accountNumber;
this.owner= owner;
this.balance=balance;
}

public int getAccountNumber() {
return accountNumber;
}
public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}
public String getOwner() {
return owner;
}
public void setOwner(String owner) {
this.owner = owner;
}
public double getBalance() {
return balance;
}
public void setBalance(double balance) {
this.balance = balance;
}

}
```

AccountClient.java

```
 package com.hibernateWithSpring;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext; 
 import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

 public class AccountClient {

 public static void main(String[] args){

    ApplicationContext context=new             FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bin/beans.xml");
    AccountDao accountdao = context.getBean("accountDaoBean",AccountDao.class);
    accountdao.createAccount(110, "varun",1000);
    accountdao.createAccount(111, "vicky",1200);
    System.out.println("account created");
    accountdao.updateBalance(111,2222);
    System.out.println("account updated");
    accountdao.deleteAccount(111);
    System.out.println("account deleted");


    List<Account> account= accountdao.getAllAccount();
    for(int i=0;i<account.size();i++){
        Account acc=account.get(i);
               System.out.println(acc.getAccountNumber()+":"+acc.getOwner()+":"+acc.getBalance());
    }

}
}
```

AccountDao.java

```
 package com.hibernateWithSpring;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

 public class AccountDao extends HibernateDaoSupport
 {

public void createAccount(int accountNumbeer, String owner, double balane){
    Account account= new Account(accountNumbeer,owner,balane);
    getHibernateTemplate().save(account); 
}

public void updateBalance(int accountNumber, double newBalance){
    Account account= getHibernateTemplate().get(Account.class, accountNumber);
    if(account !=null){
        account.setBalance(newBalance);
    }
    getHibernateTemplate().update(account);
}
public void deleteAccount(int accountNumber){
    Account account=getHibernateTemplate().get(Account.class, accountNumber);
            if(account!=null){
                getHibernateTemplate().delete(account);
            }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Account> getAllAccount()
{
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Account");
}

}
```

Account.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.hibernateWithSpring.Account" table="account">
    <id name="accountNumber" column="account_number" type="int"></id>
    <property name="owner" column="owner" type="string"></property>
    <property name="balance" column="balance" type="double"></property>
</class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="accountDaoBean" class="com.hibernateWithSpring.AccountDao">
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sfBean"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="sfBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
<property name="mappingResources">
    <value>com/hibernateWithSpring/Account.hbm.xml</value>
</property> 

<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accountdb"></property>
<property name="username" value="root"></property>
<property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

My db Details are correct But I have no idea why i am getting this error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDaoBean' defined in file [E:\new project\marsWorkspase\SpringProgram\bin\beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplateBean' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplateBean' defined in file [E:\new project\marsWorkspase\SpringProgram\bin\beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sfBean' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sfBean' defined in file [E:\new project\marsWorkspase\SpringProgram\bin\beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Things you need to fix:

1 - put the JAR (javaee-api) in your LIB folder

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0

2 - if you are using Maven, add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3 - Configure your artifact and include this jar, allowing to be deployed

4 - Put the javaee-api jar in your tomcat/jboss lib folder

Comment: after putting javaee-api jar i'am getting error:-
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext

Comment: now, do the same for hibernate dependecy.

Link for jar [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager)

Dependency

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
 <version>X.X.Xl</version>
</dependency>

Comment: where i put this tag? in which file? @victor

Comment: If you are using Maven in the Pom.xml file 
If not in your libraries manually

Comment: i am not using maven.